# How can i run a Sequelize migration to update a field with the response from an imported function?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sql-update, sequelize.js

```
'use strict';
const { getAddressCoord } = require('../../lib/geo');

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const db = queryInterface.sequelize;
    await db.query('start transaction;');
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`UPDATE users SET "homeMarket" =  ${(await 
   getAddressCoord("address")).id || null} WHERE "homeMarket" IS NULL AND "address" IS NOT 
    NULL`);
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`UPDATE users SET "homeMarketName" =  ${(await 
    getAddressCoord("address")).name || null} WHERE "homeMarket" IS NULL AND "address" IS NOT 
    NULL`);

    await db.query('commit;');
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const db = queryInterface.sequelize;
    await db.query('start transaction;');
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`UPDATE users SET "homeMarket" =  ("identity" -> 'area' 
    -> 'id')::int`);
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`UPDATE users SET "homeMarketName" =  ("identity"::json 
    -> 'area' ->> 'name')`);

    await db.query('commit;');
  },
};
```

I want the field to be updated with the response from getAddressCoord function, the getAddressCoord function takes in the address value in the column.

How can i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import and Require attempt in project.

rewrote all required functions in the migration file, and did a function call.